# Meteorjs load template depending on link

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have a page with 3 link, each link consisting of fields in a collection, and I want to click a link, and then open a new page with the template name equal to one in the collection (using the link name perhaps). I dont know if i must do this in routing or with session.

My template:

```
<template name="dgacDisplay">
<div class="row">
    {{#each dgac}}
        <div class="col-md-12 formsDisplay">
            <div>
                <p><a href="{{pathFor 'formsLayout'}}" target="_blank">{{header.reference}} - {{header.title}} - {{version}}</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Router configuration:

`this.route('dgacFormLayout', {
    path: '/dag/dgac/:name',
    data: function() {
        return Dag.findOne(this.params.name);
    }
});`

Objetc in collection (there are more):

```
if (Dag.find().count() === 0) {

Dag.insert({
    name: "a01",
    header: {
        reference: 'A01',
        title: 'Requerimento'
    },
    footer: {
        certificated : '<img alt="Certificação" src="/cert.png">'
    },
    year: '2014',
    version: 'V2.2',
    division: 'DGAC',
    counter: 0,
});
```

My page has 3 articles:

1. A01
2. A02
3. A03

I want to load template A01 when i click in A01 link, load A02 when click in link A02, and so on....

Thanks

Comment: please provide more detail; show what you have tried so far, or, for the very least show examples of these links and how they "consist of fields in a collection" -- I have a hard time imagining what you mean by that.

Comment: Have you considered using something like the iron-router package? You can define a different template/layout depending on the route. http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#layouts

Comment: I'm using iron-router.....

Comment: Then I'm not quite understanding what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it's the action property of the router which you need to set.

I setup a little test with meteorpad and it's working pretty well.

http://meteorpad.com/pad/ibgSo89PnRXYmu82B/Iron:Router%20Basics

Just add a similar action function like in my test setup.

```
this.route('dgacFormLayout', {
    path: '/dag/dgac/:name',
    data: function() {
        return Dag.findOne(this.params.name);
    }
    action: function() {
        var page = Dag.findOne(this.params.name);
        if(page) this.render(page.tpl);
        else this.render('pageNotFound');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this solve one of my problems. The other problem is my knowledge in Meteor, i need to learn more :) Any good advice?

thanks

Comment: Nice the answer helped you out! Here you go with a list to check out :) https://github.com/ericdouglas/Meteor-Learning the book "Discover Meteor" is also on the list and a nice start.